# Booting Linux off a SD Card

Tags: linux, tails

I have a work tablet/laptop that is currently running win8.1
i am interested in running Tails on this machine,how would i go about doing so ?
how large should the sd Card be,since tails is 1gb,would a 2gb SD card will be fine ?

Machine in question is the Asus Transformer 100T

Comment: I think it would be good to mention the 100T in the question's title, because it really scopes down the question *and* the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Running Linux on the T100 is tricky, as a quick search through various forums will show. It also seems that using an SD card to boot from this device is not really supported, while booting from USB is.

http://liliputing.com/2013/10/booting-ubuntu-asus-transformer-book-t100.html - make sure to read the comments on the article for additional insights.

> I was able to take Ubuntu 13.04 Linux for a spin on the Asus
>   Transformer Book T100. At this point, bunch of key features don’t work
>   yet, including WiFi or touchscreen support — and the screen resolution
>   is stuck at 800 x 600 pixels. Ubuntu 13.10 won’t boot.
>
> As of late October, 2013 it’s actually pretty tricky to convince the
>   Asus Transformer Book T100 to boot anything other than Windows 8.1.
>   It’s easy to get to the Windows advanced boot options or the UEFI
>   firmware options and spot the options that should let you boot a
>   different operating system from external storage. But most operating
>   systems won’t boot, and will instead just dump you back into the
>   Windows bootloader.
>
> Warning: Note that these steps might not work for everyone — and if
>   you accidentally end up with a computer that won’t boot, I’ll offer
>   some troubleshooting tips, but you’re entirely responsible for
>   breaking (and hopefully fixing) your own device.
>
> Preparing a bootable Ubuntu 13.04 USB flash drive
>
> 1. Download ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso from the Ubuntu download page. Newer versions of Ubuntu don’t yet seem to work.
> 2. Download Rufus, a tool for creating bootable USB drives.
> 3. Download and unzip paperWastage’s bootia32.ubuntu_13.04_x64.zip file.
> 4. Plug a 1GB or larger USB flash drive into your computer.
> 5. Double-click the Rufus file you downloaded to launch the utility.
> 6. Choose the drive letter for the flash drive you jut plugged in under the “Device” drop-down menu.
> 7. Use the following settings: GPT partition scheme, FAT file system, 64 kilobyte cluster size.
> 8. Make sure the box that says “Create a bootable disk using” is checked, and choose “ISO Image” and click the drive icon on the right
>      to open an Explorer window and find your Ubuntu 64-bit disk image.
> 9. Click start.
>
> At this point, your computer will format the flash drive (and erase
>   any data that’s already on it — so make sure to backup any important
>   files) and prepare it as a bootable drive that lets you run or install
>   Ubuntu.
>
> When the process is complete, move on to the next step.
>
> 10. Open an Explorer window and navigate to the newly prepared flash drive.
> 11. There should be a folder labeled “EFI.” Click it to open that folder. Then click the folder labeled “BOOT” to navigate to that
>       folder.
> 12. Copy the bootia32.efi file from step 3 into this folder (make sure you’ve unzipped it first).
>
> That’s it. Your flash drive is now ready. Go ahead and eject it from
>   your PC.
>
> Booting Ubuntu on the Asus Transformer Book T100
>
> The first thing we need to do is disable secure boot on the
>   Transformer Book. That’s pretty easy to do, with these steps. Note
>   that you can complete these steps with the USB drive plugged in or
>   without it — but I had a bit more luck without it.
>
> 1. Swipe from the right side of the screen to bring up the Charms menu.
> 2. Tap “Settings.”
> 3. Choose the “Change PC settings” option at the bottom.
> 4. On the following screen tap “Update and recovery.”
> 5. At the next screen, choose “recovery.”
> 6. Under the Advanced startup section, choose “Restart now.”
> 7. This will reboot your device to a blue screen with large icons. Choose the one that says Troubleshoot.
> 8. At the following screen choose “Advanced Options.”
> 9. Next, select “UEFI Firmware Settings.
> 10. Finally hit the “Restart” button.
>
> This will reboot your device into the UEFI settings area, which looks
>   like an old-school BIOS menu. The touchscreen and touchpad won’t work
>   here, but you can navigate using the arrow keys and enter key on the
>   keyboard.
>
> 11. Use the arrow keys to get to the Security tab.
> 12. Scroll down to Secure Boot menu and hit “Enter.
> 13. Make sure Secure Boot Support is selected, and hit Enter again to bring up a screen that says “Enabled” or “Disabled.”
> 14. Choose Disabled and hit enter.
> 15. Hit the Esc key.
>
> Now Secure Boot is disabled. You could theoretically save and exit at
>   this point. But instead, this is the time when I’d recommend plugging
>   in the USB flash drive.
>
> Once it’s plugged in, move on to the next step.
>
> 16. Move over to the Save & Exit tab, highlight “Save Changes and Exit” and hit Enter.
> 17. As the system reboots, press and hold the F2 key so that you return to the UEFI Settings menu.
> 18. This time when you navigate to the Save & Exit menu you should see an option under Boot Overried that says “UEFI” and has the name of
>       your USB flash drive.
> 19. Select that boot override option and hit enter.
>
> If all goes according to plan, your device should now boot into a GRUB
>   bootloader menu, giving you the option of trying or installing Ubuntu.
>
> I strongly suggest you use the “Try Ubuntu without installing” option
>   at this point — unless you really know what you’re doing. This will
>   let you run Ubuntu without altering your Windows files at all.
>
> Getting past the command line.
>
> We’re not quite done yet though. While Ubuntu should boot up on your
>   system at this point, you’ll probably see the Ubuntu logo for a moment
>   or two and then get dumped out at a command prompt.
>
> Here’s how to get past that point:
>
> 1. Type the following commands, and hit enter after each.
> 2. cd /
> 3. cd usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/
> 4. sudo rm vesa_drv.so
> 5. startx
>
> You should see a flurry of text scroll by and then a mouse cursor will
>   appear on screen. A moment later, you should see the full Ubuntu Unity
>   desktop environment.
>
> Keep in mind, you won’t be able to use WiFi out of the box, since
>   Ubuntu doesn’t recognize the device’s wireless adapter. The screen
>   resolution will be stuck at 800 x 600, which could look funny. And
>   there’s no touchscreen support — so while you can detach the screen
>   from the keyboard, you won’t be able to do much with it.
>
> The user interface may also be a bit sluggish — in order to get the X
>   Server to load a graphical user interface, we had to delete the vesa
>   graphics driver. It may be possible to load an alternate driver to
>   improve performance.
>
> But now that we know it’s possible to get alternate operating systems
>   to boot on the Transformer Book T100, it should also be possible for
>   people to figure out how to configure them to take advantage of the
>   tablet/notebook hybrid’s hardware.
>
> How do I get back to Windows?
>
> When you logout of Ubuntu you can shut down or restart the computer.
>   If the system freezes (or you’re impatient), you can also press and
>   hold the power button until the tablet shuts down.
>
> You  can then press and hold it again to restart the tablet.
>   Unfortunately, you’ll probably be greeted by a screen with the Asus
>   logo and the text “Preparing BitLocker recovery.”
>
> Here’s how to get back to Windows from here:
>
> 1. Wait until you see a blue screen and choose the “Skip this drive” link at the bottom of the page.
>
> This’ll take you to a troubleshoot screen like we saw in the section
>   above. The only difference is you can use the keyboard and touchpad to
>   make your selections, but not the touchscreen.
>
> 2. Choose “Troubleshoot” and then “Advanced Options” again, and then select “UEFI Firmware Settings” and hit Restart.
> 3. Move over to the “Save & Exit” tab and select “Restore Defaults” and hit Enter.
> 4. Save Changes and Exit and you should reboot into Windows.